# How to generate a unique identifier for a hash with a certain content?

Tags: ruby, hash

For a caching layer, I need to create a unique sha for a hash. It should be unique for the content of that hash. Two hashes with the same config should have the same sha.

```
in_2014 = { scopes: [1, 2, 3], year: 2014 }
not_in_2104 = { scopes: [1, 2, 3], year: 2015 }
also_in_2014 = { year: 2014, scopes: [1, 2, 3] }

in_2014 == also_in_2014 #=> true
not_in_2104 == in_2014  #=> false
```

Now, in order to store it and quickly look this up, it need to be turned
into something of a shasum. Simply converting to string does not work,
so generating a hexdigest from it does not work either:

```
require 'digest'
in_2014.to_s == also_in_2014.to_s #=> false
Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(in_2014.to_s) == Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(also_in_2014.to_s) #=> false
```

What I want is a shasum or some other identifier that will allow me to
compare the hashes with one another. I want something like the last test that will return true if the contents of the hashes match.

I could sort the hashes before `to_s`, yet that seems cludgy to me. I
am, for one, afraid that I am overlooking something there (a `sort` returns an array, no longer a hash, for one). Is there
something simple that I am overlooking? Or is this not possible at all?

FWIW, we need this in a scenario like below:

```
Analysis.find_by_config({scopes: [1,2], year: 2014}).datasets
Analysis.find_by_config({account_id: 1337}).datasets

class Analysis < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.find_by_config(config)
    self.find_by(config_digest: shasum_of(config))
  end

  def self.shasum_of(config)
     #WAT?
  end

  def before_saving
    self.config_digest = Analysis.shasum_of(config)
  end
end
```

Note that here, Analysis does *not* have columns "scopes" or "year" or
"account_id". These are arbitrary configs, that we only need for looking
up the datasets.

Comment: If it's a cache, does it really matter if you've occasional duplicate entries?

Comment: Duplicate entries will matter in some cases. The cache is there, because generating the "datasets" is really (as in ten minutes of computing time per config) expensive. Hence we want to store the config, have a background worker calculate the datasets and from then on, serve the datasets for a certain config right away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend the `hash` method because it is unreliable. You can quickly confirm this by executing `{one: 1}.hash` in your IRB, the same command in your Rails console, and then in the IRB and/or Rails Console on another machine. The outputs will differ.

Sticking with `Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(string)` would be wiser.

You'll have to sort the hash and stringify it of course. This is what I would do:

```
hash.sort.to_s
```

If you don't want an array, for whatever reason, turn it back into a hash.

```
Hash[hash.sort].to_s #=> will return hash
```

And, for whatever reason, if you don't want to turn the hash into an array and then back into a hash, do the following for hash-to-sorted-hash:

```
def prepare_for_sum( hash )
  hash.keys.sort.each_with_object({}) do |key, return_hash|
    return_hash[key] = hash[key]
  end.to_s
end
```

Using some modifications in the method above, you can sort the values too; it can be helpful in case of Array or Hash values.

Comment: `Hash[hash.sort].to_s` throws an error, `can't convert array into hash`.

Comment: @berkes, works fine for the hash I've provided in my response.

Comment: we are investigating, because our codebase got different results. Will post back when I have more details.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, Ruby has a method for this exact case: [`Hash.hash`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html#method-i-hash).

```
in_2014.hash == also_in_2014.hash
```

Comment: `hash` has its drawbacks. Check out my answer.

Comment: @Humza is right, this is a terrible idea for a cache, `hash` values will not be constant across processes.